# Как отследить событие по ID в Array

Tags: javascript, массивы

Итак, есть корзина - массив **products** в который добавляются элементы, созданные с помощью класса **Product**. Есть еще один массив **cardAddArr**, который состоит из кнопок запуска класса **Product**. По клику на одной из кнопок массива **cardAddArr** в массив **products** добавляется новый элемент. Чтобы удалить элемент внутри корзины (по повторному клику на кнопке **cardAdd**), используется метод *splice*, для которого нужно указать точный индекс элемента, то есть порядковый номер элемента в массиве. Проблема в том, что индексы массивов **cardAddArr** и **products** могут не совпадать! Потому что пользователь мог нажимать кнопки сначала в одном порядке (добавляя элементы), а потом в другом. Так как же быть?

---

Добавляю ID внутрь класса **Product**, но как заставить функцию *removeProduct* удалять элементы не по индексу, а по ID?

---

ссылка на проект с корзиной

[http://igorbobyrev.ru/homeworks/funiro/](https://igorbobyrev.ru/homeworks/funiro/)

```js
const cardAddArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".card__basket")); //кнопка добавить в корзину
const cart = document.querySelector("#cart");  //кнопка корзины

class Cart {
    products;
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
    }
    addProduct(product) {
        this.products.push(product);
    }
    removeProduct(index) {
        this.products.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

class Product {
    imageSrc;
    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
    id;
    constructor(card) {
        this.imageSrc = card.querySelector(".card__image").children[0].src;
        // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
        // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
        // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
        this.id = card.querySelector(".card__basket").dataset.id;
    }
};

const myCart = new Cart();

myCart.products = cardAddArr.forEach((cardAdd, i) => {
    cardAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const card = e.target.closest(".card");
        const product = new Product(card);
        if (cardAdd.classList.contains("added")) {
            cardAdd.classList.remove("added");
            myCart.removeProduct(i);
            cardAdd.textContent = "Add to cart";
            basketBlockFill();
        } else {
            cardAdd.classList.add("added");
            myCart.addProduct(product);
            cardAdd.textContent = "Already inside";
        }; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне нужно было по повторному клику на кнопке добавления нового продукта в массив удалить элемент, полученный при первом клике на этой кнопке.
Я знаю по крайней мере о трех способах удаления элемента из массива: delete, splice и filter. Delete мне не подошел, т.к. он не удалял элемент а только его свойства, нужно было сразу вставлять функцию рендеринга корзины. Splice мне не подошел, потому что он удаляет по индексу, а проблему с индексом я описал в вопросе. И я воспользовался методом filter, для работы которого нужно было указать условия - в качестве них я поставил равенство кнопки и продукта по ID

```js
myCart.products = cardAddArr.forEach((cardAdd, id) => {

        cardAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            const card = e.target.closest(".card");

            const product = new Product(card);
            const savedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
            myCart.products = savedCart.products;
            if (cardAdd.classList.contains("added")) {
                cardAdd.classList.remove("added");
                let cardId = e.target.dataset.id;  
                // нахожу ID кнопки на карточке
                let newArray = myCart.products.filter((product) => 
                product.id !== cardId); 
                // сравниваю ID нового продукта в корзине и ID карточки,
                // и получаю новый массив, без нажатого продукта
                myCart.products = newArray; 
                // обратно загоняю всё в старый массив

                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(myCart));
                cartNum.textContent = myCart.count; 
                cardAdd.textContent = "Add to cart";
                basketBlockFill();
            } else {
                cardAdd.classList.add("added");
                myCart.addProduct(product);
                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(myCart));
                cartNum.textContent = myCart.count;
                cardAdd.textContent = "Already inside";
            }; 
        });
```